# Does XSSFWorkbook library accept csv format files?

Tags: java

I am using data validation for excel and CSV files. 
XSSFWorkbook library works for excel. 
Does it also work for CSV format??

Comment: You have to write your own CSV parser. You might also want to look at my library https://github.com/xzel23/meja, which should make this easier.  Contact me if you want some sample code for your problem (but I will perhaps not have time before the weekend).

Comment: thanx for the help.